# Laravel Paypal Apis Difference

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, payment-gateway, laravel-api

I have worked on Paypal Payment Gateway Integration Projects in Laravel project.
I mostly used `Paypal/Paypal-php-sdk` package. [Here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK)

But I came to know about `srmklive/laravel-paypal` package which looks more easier. [Here](https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal).

I think above two payment Apis are working slightly different.
First of all, I took api keys from different places in Paypal account.

In `Php-paypal-sdk` package, I got two API keys, Paypal Client ID and Paypal Secret Key.
And in `srmklive/laravel-paypal`  package, I got three API keys, API username, API password, API Certificate Key.

Can anyone have better knowledge about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The composer package `paypal/rest-api-sdk-php` uses the REST API (v1) as referenced here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/

However I noticed there also appear to be `/v2/` endpoints, as found here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/ . I'm not sure why this package uses the v1 version; I couldnt find much information about it.

---

- The package `srmklive/laravel-paypal` uses the *deprecated* NVP/SOAP API. According to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/express-checkout/, it is deprecated since January 1, 2017.

As quoted in the readme https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal:

> Currently only PayPal Express Checkout API Is Supported.

So you're probably better off using the first package. However I do remember that the APIs are not interchangeable, i.e. not all functions are implemented in both APIs. I remember vaguely something about recurring payments not available in one or the other.

Another reason you'd also want to use the first package is because it is a 1st party package (created by PayPal), so it's probably more complete and closer to the source.

Comment: Well, here is rest api v2. https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-php-SDK/tree/2.0-beta

Comment: srmklive/laravel-paypal package seemed more easier for recurring payment than first. That's why i wanted to use it. But for now, it won't work?

Comment: Not sure I havent used both packages in months